# How do I transform the series by taking a span of 15 elements and averaging them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this code with pandas (sorry for my english...):

```
dataset = read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
dataset.plot(figsize=(12,6))
```

In file data.csv is data like this:

```
               0
0     2481.05700
1     2481.05955
2     2481.06895
3     2481.06770
4     2481.06075
3053  2481.80190
3054  2481.78990
3055  2481.79275
3056  2481.78220
3057  2481.76360
```

I need to transform the series so that each span of 15 elements is averaged.
I've seen the *resample* method used for similar tasks. But how to use it correctly for this situation, I don't know.

Comment: So, this is a time series, right? If yes, is it a regular time series? What is the time interval between each observation? I'm asking this because the pandas resample the data need to be indexed by timedate values...

Comment: @HemersonTacon. Each value is taken by the minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking something like this, to group the dataframe in groups of 15:

```
dataset.groupby(dataset.index//15).mean()
```

---

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":range(10)})
df
#   A
#0  0
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
#4  4
#5  5
#6  6
#7  7
#8  8
#9  9
df.groupby(df.index//2).mean()
#     A
#0  0.5
#1  2.5
#2  4.5
#3  6.5
#4  8.5
```